# Very distant point lights don't render properly

Tags: three.js, aframe

If I try to scale up a working scene with one sphere and point lighting to make the distances between the objects very large ( > 1E5 ), then the rendered lighting is incorrect - it looks like a tiny slit which moves across the object as one's VR viewpoint changes when I display on an Oculus Quest or indeed Google Cardboard. The scene looks correct in a non-VR web browser on a desktop.

This is clearly an issue with distances, precision, and the a-sphere object and how it reacts with lights and cameras at large distances. But what I need is a workaround. I'm trying to simulate the solar system at real scale ( at least as far as distances between planets goes ). For the moon to be far enough from the observer not to move when I move around, I need to scale it so the moon is at least 2000 m from the camera. That puts the sun at 800000 m away, and that's where sunlight comes from. As a result, the other planets are not rendered correctly.
If I scale downwards, all works, but the moon moves relative to the other objects when I stand up or walk around.

Is there a workaround I can use here? Is there a published limit which explains which bit of the system is the problem - it's clearly more likely to be at a lower level than aframe, but I'm not sure if it's three.js or the webgl implementation on the oculus or what.

```
<a-scene background="color:black;">
  <a-sphere id="mars" position="0 500E3 -2000E3" radius="40E3" color="#FFBBBB"></a-sphere>
  <a-entity id="sunlightnear" light="color: #00FF00; type: point;" position="0 0 -1000"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="sunlightfar" light="color: #FF0000; type: point;" position="0 0 -1000E3"></a-entity>
  <a-entity id="mainCamera" camera="far:1E10;" position="0 1.6 0"  look-controls></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

This uses two lights at different distances. I would expect the mars sphere to be evenly illuminated. Instead it is always visibly green from the first light but the red from the second light appears as a band which moves across the sphere with weird artifacts as I move my eye.

Comment: I've recreated the scene described entirely on three.js and I can't see the behaviour you described. I'm not familiar with how a-frame works exactly, but the problem doesn't seem to be with three.js implementation [three.js example](https://codepen.io/sciecode/pen/KKKZwPN)

Comment: Hi Thanks for doing that. I've tried running your version on the oculus but have to play around with it to get it to go into vr mode so I can see what happens. But I note that you are using the lambert material, and that may explain the difference as a-frame doesn't offer that out of the box ( although one could create a custom shader which used it). I will try some experiments and report back.

Comment: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-create-VR-content this might help you, I don't own a VR to experiment with :(

Comment: By the way, I've tested with different materials and the result was the same. Updated the example with `Phong` just to illustrate.

Comment: Just tried myself. On the oculus, it works with everything but MeshPhysicalMaterial, which it turns out is the only non-flat choice built into aframe. I can find a way of using the Lambert or Phong materials by writing some boilerplate I think. But it would be nice to know if this is a bug in PhysicalMaterial or a necessary limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use point lights. If the light source is very far or very big is better approximated with a [directional light](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/light.html#properties_type)

[Example](https://gusty-table.glitch.me/) and corresponding [HTML](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/gusty-table?path=index.html:11:66).

I also recommend using small numbers. Easier to work with and won't run into precision or overflow issues. Better to focus on getting distance and size ratios correct.

Comment: I know that directional lights and small numbers will solve the rendering problem, but I can't use those in a solar system simulation, since the sun comes from a different direction relative to each planet. Similarly, if I scale everything to a much smaller size, it renders correctly until I move around the immediate environment, at which point closer objects are displaced.